# Would a custom IP-based protocol work?

Tags: ip, tcp

Let's say somebody invented a new protocol I would put on top of IP. Would two computers from the other ends of the world be able to communicate with it, i.e. would routers forward the frames that aren't standard TCP/UDP/ICMP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if it is build on top of IP then it would be routable over the internet.  The IP protocol defines the header and payload.  The header is used for routing.  So you would be able to send custom IP-based protocol data from one computer to another over the internet.

However, both computers will need custom drivers to send, receive and understand the data.

I'm not sure why you'd bother though.  If you're sending custom data, you're much better off writing an application level protocol on top of tcp or udp and take advantage of the networking layer built into all computers and operating systems already.  It'll be easier to write, maintain, and debug.